# app runs well in android studio but cannot be installed on my phone

Tags: android-studio

I have developed a simple app by android studio. the app works well on emulator, still I cannot install that on my phone and whenever I want to install the app I get this message "app not available". I have tried cleaning the built and rebuilding the app, still nothing. I checked others problem, my code has the Main and Launcher section inside. any tips or helps appreciated.

````
\<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?\>
\<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"\>

    //<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Advanture"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".Shelter"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".GameScreen"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

\</manifest\>```
````